# Inferring Data Type While Streaming In Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, casting, type-conversion, python-polars

I was recently given larger-than-memory parquet file where every column is a string data type. I'd like to do type inference, converting the columns that can be converted into ints and floats, and keeping the properly string columns as strings, then sinking to a new parquet file with the proper types. Any suggestions on how to do this?

I've tried doing some casting with the built in cast functions and setting `strict=False`, but that ends up turning all of the strings to null.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an example (file) that reproduces the issue - possibly, while setting `infer_schema_length` really low.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Hericks there is no `infer_schema_length` for parquet files. The dtypes are explicitly stored in metadata.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Thanks! For some reason I skipped reading the parquet-part and considered the `scan_csv` case.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a built in way to do this directly. The problem is that a column has to be a single dtype and when you sink to a file, polars has to know the output schema before it actually starts streaming (aka even looking at the first row) of the input data. Well there's a contradiction because you don't know if your string to int or string to float conversion will work until you've already read all of the data.

That means you have to do 2 passes through the data. One pass to see which columns can be cast to which dtype and then the second pass to actually sink the data.

Here's a function to help with the first part

```
def try_dtype(lf, dtype, cols_to_skip=None):
    from polars.exceptions import ComputeError
    if cols_to_skip is None:
        cols_to_check = [x for x,y in lf.schema.items() if y==pl.String]
    else:
        cols_to_check = [
            x for x,y in lf.schema.items() 
            if y==pl.String and 
            x not in cols_to_skip]
    if len(cols_to_check)==0:
        return []
    good_cols=[]
    for col in cols_to_check:
        try:
            (
                lf
                .select(pl.col(col).cast(dtype))
                .collect(streaming=True)
            )
            good_cols.append(col)
        except ComputeError:
            pass
    return good_cols
```

With this function you'd then do something like:

```
lf = pl.scan_parquet('your_big_file.parquet')

### try int first otherwise everything will be float
int_cols = try_dtype(lf, pl.Int64)

float_cols = try_dtype(lf, pl.Float64, int_cols)

exprs = []
for col in lf.columns:
    if col in int_cols:
        exprs.append(pl.col(col).cast(pl.Int64))
    elif col in float_cols:
        exprs.append(pl.col(col).cast(pl.Float64))
    else:
        exprs.append(pl.col(col))
lf.select(*exprs).sink_parquet('final_cast.parquet')
```